# Google Maps: “Unsupported Link Google Maps can't open this link” but only the first time

Tags: google-maps

My Wayfinder PWA hands over to Google Maps to show directions to campus buildings. The links comply to the advice given on https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide. On iOS, the first time you try to use the links, Google Maps open with the error "Unsupported Link". Subsequent attempts work as expected.

Here's a link example:
https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&destination=52.4055882,-1.5035222&travelmode=walking
as found on the Wayfinder app at https://wayfinder.coventry.ac.uk/buildings/alison-gingell.html?location=coventry-university

I've tried encoding the string with encodeURL() but this does not seem to make any difference in the output or the behaviour.

```
googleMapLink() {
  let link =
    'https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&destination=' +
    this.destination.lat +
    ',' +
    this.destination.lng +
    '&travelmode=walking'
  return link
}
```

**UPDATE**:
Looking at the links that @xomena shared, it is a known issue. It seems that it might be the travelmode parameter that is a contributing factor. I tried without it and it works fine. Acceptable workaround. Thanks @xomena.

```
googleMapLink() {
      let link =
        'https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&destination=' +
        this.destination.lat +
        ',' +
        this.destination.lng
      return link
    }
```

Comment: It sounds like this bug: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/74514340

Comment: Or probably this one: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/130991538

Comment: Thanks to those links, there was enough of a clue to find an acceptable workaround. Thanks @xomena

Comment: Today I created link from Google Maps and received such problem. Google Maps App can’t create valid link for itself?!

Answer (score 0):

You could also use this URL https://maps.google.com/?saddr=start&daddr=end. This worked for me.
The maps/ or maps/dir/ URL will not work in mobile iOS/Android Google Maps app.